# PHP/MSSQL - Filtering from User Input (HTML)

Tags: php, sql, sql-server, filter, user-input

I have been given this assignment, to include some sort of filtering to my current SQL query via User Input.
Basically, i am looking for a filtering option, whether its some kind of menu or button, really doesn't matter. My mssql is as follows:

```
SELECT TOP 10 Test_Database.Distributor, Test_Database.Value
    FROM Test_Database
    WHERE Test_Database.Week = '(USER INPUT GOES HERE)'
    GROUP BY Distributor 
    ORDER BY Value desc
```

How can i make the `WHERE` statement a User Input? For instance.. A client wants to see the given value of some distributor, but in the week/month/year of the clients choice.

Regards

Comment: entire where clause need to be an user input or just values in where clause?

Comment: The values should be user input.

Say the user was given a drop down menu where he could choose from 1-52 weeks, and then it would implement the number into that sql sentence. Choose week 32 -> WHERE Test_Database.Week = '32'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 You can do that simply by introducing if else statement
 $where  = "";
 //receive filter option  example $_GET['week']  
  //Do some sanitizing for $_GET['week']
  if ($_GET['week']) {
  $where  =  "WHERE Test_Database.Week = $_GET['week']"
 } else if (somecondition) {
  $where  = "some query";
  }
```

//You can add multiple condition by concatenating $where, but make sure where not repeats

```
$query = "SELECT TOP 10 Test_Database.Distributor, Test_Database.Value
FROM Test_Database
$where  
GROUP BY Distributor
ORDER BY Value desc "
```

Comment: That sure looks like the solution im looking for!

This might be asking a lot, but im going for it anyway.. How am i to implement this into some kind usable HTML. ?

Comment: As suggested by the below user please santize the input from user.

You have to run the query and get the results. 

Based on the results you can plot the HTML table or any other format you like

Answer (score 0):

i m not sure but maybe you can try.

```
<input type="text" name="week"/>
```

Post this textbox value in select page and set that value in where close.

Comment: Im looking for the SQL/PHP sentence that somehow can pull out client specified week

Answer (score 0):

there should not be ANY data from user in sql query

that did not pass filter

sql-injection is not an empty word

*so no $_GET['week'] in sql if you didn't clear it*

Comment: The weeks from 1-52 is already declared in Test_Database.Week.

I just want to know how the client/user can choose between them.