# Make a dynamic query to mysql from php

Tags: php, mysql

I want to create a page when a user can select like in a drop-down menu the fields to make a query in a simple mySql database, and then print on the screen the results.

Some suggestions?

Comment: My suggestion is to try writing some code and then asking for advice on things you cannot manage to do : )

Comment: :) i know how to make a sql query with php, a static query i mean, i'm not able to managing for instance a page when i select fields and make a dynamic query.

Comment: You may use some `$query= "SELECT ... FROM ... WHERE val=$val`, and populate `$val` with PHP. Then send the `$query` to MySQL and have tons of results to fetch.

Answer (score 0):

If you have Microsoft Access, look at the way queries are generated as you select fields with the GUI (switch to SQL view to see the query).

Answer (score 0):

Simply generate a HTML Form that lists the available options from the Database and then from the end user's input, Concatenate the input/strings together to make up a valid MySQL Query that would be returned.

But it's you who's got to do the actual coding ;)

Answer (score 0):

Check my answer here ..Similar kind of question.Hope it help

[PHP/MSSQL - Filtering from User Input (HTML)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14603807/php-mssql-filtering-from-user-input-html/14604096#14604096)

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like:

```
$get_dropdown_value=isset($_REQUEST["result"])?$_REQUEST["result"]:"";

//Query
mysql_query("SELECT * FROM $get_dropdown_value");
```

get the dropdown value from your code. and assign that in `$get_dropdown_value`.

Comment: When you pass values from user to mysql, remember to always use proper quoting (in this case `mysql_real_escape_string()`) and check user input.