# Auto submit form and MYSQL requery

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I have been using this code to display some testimonials in my website.

This is code so far :

```
// Select testimonials from database 
$q = "SELECT testimonial, city_name, name, web_address, image_name, membership_type
        FROM testimonials 
        INNER JOIN city ON city.city_id = testimonials.city_id
        ORDER BY date_added DESC LIMIT $start, $display";

$r = mysqli_query($dbc, $q); 

if ( $records >= 1 ) {

    while ( $row = mysqli_fetch_array( $r, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
        $testimonial = $row['testimonial'];
        //echo $testimonial;
        $mytestimonial = nl2br($testimonial);
        $city               = $row['city_name'];
        $name               = $row['name'];
        $url                = $row['web_address'];
        $imageName      = $row['image_name'];
        $type               = $row['membership_type'];

        echo '<div class="testimonial-row">
                    <div class="testimonial-image">
                        <img src="'.UPLOAD_DIR.$imageName.'" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="testimonial">
                        <h2>'.$name.'</h2>
                        <h3>';
                        if($type==1){
                            echo 'A teacher';
                        }elseif($type==2){
                            echo 'An Institute';
                        }elseif($type==3){
                            echo 'A Student';
                        }
                        echo " from <strong>$city</strong></h3>
                        <blockquote>$mytestimonial</blockquote>
                        <p class='user-url'><a href=''>$url</a></p>
                    </div>                  
                </div>";    
    }
} else {
    echo "There is no any testimonial to display at this time. Please try again later.";
}
```

After running above code I can display all my testimonials. I have 3 different kind of testimonials and at the moment display all kind of testimonials together in my page.

Now I am going a solution with a select box to filter and display them according to its type.

This is my select box :

```
<select class="select" name="type">
    <option value="1">Tutor</option>
    <option value="2">Institute</option>
    <option value="3">Student</option>
</select>
```

When selecting an option from select box my filtering should happen with requering my original query with selected type. I got a solution with jquery show/hide function but its not match with desired result.

NOTE: I cant use a submit button with this select box. Thats why I am looking for a solution with Ajax or Jquery.

Can anyone tell me is it possible or not?

Thank you.

Comment: definately you can.... on change event of select box .. call ajax which will filter your result ...

Comment: Can I know how can I do it? I tried it with jquery but couldn't get it to work.

Comment: May be will help you 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14603807/php-mssql-filtering-from-user-input-html/14604096#14604096

Comment: @TNK   see this blog http://itsphptime.blogspot.in/2013/03/using-ajax-and-php-to-change-value-of.html   if you still require code tell me..because it will take sometime to write code for this

Comment: thanks for yours great links.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may be Solution...
Pass your Value like this :

```
                    <select name="jumpMenu" class="sort-by-select" id="jumpMenu" onchange="MM_jumpMenu('parent',this,0)">
                      <option value=""> Select type </option>
                      <option value ="yourpage?type=1">Tutor</option>
                      <option value ="yourpage?type=2">Institute</option>
                      <option value ="yourpage?type=3">Student</option>

                    </select>

 <script type="text/javascript">
function MM_jumpMenu(targ,selObj,restore) //v3.0
{ 
    eval(targ+".location='"+selObj.options[selObj.selectedIndex].value+"'");
    if (restore) selObj.selectedIndex=0;
}
</script>
```

After that get that value like this..

```
 if(isset($_GET['type']) && $_GET['type'] != "")
 {
$Q = $_GET['type'];
  }
```

Put this value in Query

```
 SELECT testimonial, city_name, name, web_address, image_name, membership_type
    FROM testimonials 
    INNER JOIN city ON city.city_id = testimonials.city_id where membership_type='$Q'
    ORDER BY date_added DESC LIMIT $start, $display
```

Comment: thanks for response. Can you tell me how can I requery my original one

Comment: But this code is not working my pagination. can you tell me the reason?

Comment: Its ok. Now its working for me. But can't understand javascript part. If you have time explain it little. Anyway thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

Here is code sample code that can give you some idea what I was suggesting to you ..

```
$(document).ready(function(){


 $('#type').change(function(){
   var data = $("#type").val();
$.ajax({

         url : "yourdomain/yourfilterpage.php",
         data: {'type':data},
         type : 'POST' ,
         success : function(data){ $('#divtoshowdata').html(data)}
     });
 })

})

 <select class="select" name="type" id='type'>
 <option value="1">Tutor</option>
<option value="2">Institute</option> 
<option value="3">Student</option>
```

on yourfilterpage.php get your filtered result